# Android FileProvider class not found in release builds

Tags: android, proguard, android-support-library

I'm using a FileProvider to get photos from the device. The implementation works just fine in debug builds (minifyEnabled false) but when I'm building the release build (minifyEnabled true) I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package.name-2/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/om.package.name-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

So I guess this has someting to do with the proguard setup

I have

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
```

which is a superset of v4 in my gradle file and

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 23
```

and

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.content.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.content.** { *; }
-keep class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
```

in my proguard-rules.pro file

I have tested with both Android 5 and 6 and same thing happens.
Any suggestion would be usefull, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this link. It might help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44458490/2054348](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44458490/2054348)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/52813496/5460053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using **`androidx`** library and getting the same error. So, in **`AndroidManifest.xml`**, I changed this line:

```
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
```

to this:

```
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
```

Answer (score 18):

The following worked for me:

In your module build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
...
multiDexEnabled true
...
```

}

Then:

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
...
```

}

And finally, ensure that your application class has one of the following:

A. If you do *not* extend your application class:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

B. If you *do* extend your Application class and but can change the base class:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

C. If you *do* extend your Application class and cannot change the base class:

```
  public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

For more info:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: Hello @Munier Parker, I have done all these but still getting same issue.

Answer (score -2):

After a couple of hours of more googling around I've ended up updating gradle and google services to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
}
```

previously the version ware

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

I guess there needs to be something with the google-services library

Comment: What does **com.google.gms:google-services** have to do with `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`?